# Does function type of callback work in class?

Tags: ros, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am wondering if I can use function type of callback in a class?

This is my function type callback signature:

```
double current_joint_position[7];
double current_joint_velocity[7];
void controllerStateCB(const pr2_controllers_msgs::JointTrajectoryControllerState::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    for (int joint_index = 0; joint_index < 7; joint_index++)
    {
        current_joint_position[joint_index]=msg->actual.positions[joint_index];
        current_joint_velocity[joint_index]=msg->actual.velocities[joint_index];
    }
}
```

This is where I define the subscriber:

```
void move_group::MoveGroupMoveAction::executeMoveCallback_PlanOnly(const moveit_msgs::MoveGroupGoalConstPtr& goal, moveit_msgs::MoveGroupResult &action_res)
{
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ros::NodeHandle handle;
  ros::Subscriber sub = handle.subscribe("r_arm_controller/state", 1000, &controllerStateCB);
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

The function signature is in the same cpp file of the class.

However, it seems that the callback function is never called even though there is message in "r_arm_controller/state" topic.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Quan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101771/does-function-type-of-callback-work-in-class?/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2013-11-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2013-11-17**:
Thank you tbh, I just miss spin in  my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where is your spin? Callbacks won't happen until you reach a spin. So if your subscriber goes out of scope and is deleted before a spin happens, it won't do anything.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can certainly have callbacks be class methods, but the subscriber instantiator requires an additional argument.  [This page](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Callback_Types) on subscribers and publishers explains in more detail.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-11-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can call a non-class callback from a subscriber that's within another class. As a minimal example, something like this works:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/Empty.h"

void emptyCallback(const std_msgs::Empty::ConstPtr& msg) {
  ROS_INFO("Got empty message!");
}

class Listener {
  ros::NodeHandle nh_;
  ros::Subscriber sub_;
public:
  Listener(): nh_("") {
    sub_ = nh_.subscribe("empty_msg", 1000, &emptyCallback);
    ROS_INFO("done constructing Listener!");
  };
  ~Listener() {};
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "test_cb_node");
  Listener my_listener = Listener();
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-11-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1